# Emotion based reasoning experiments

Tags: intuition

Do experiments exist that show that reasoning is [or isn't] highly biased by emotions?

I'm looking for experiments showing that people perceive a situation differently depending on how they feel about the circumstances - for example, you estimate your chances of winning in a chess game lower than they are once you've lost the queen.

Comment: How about these? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_and_cold_cognition#Hot_function_tasks

Comment: This is a very Broad Question :). However, there are a lot of studies about "mood as Information", that influences our judging and cognition in general. I have the following puplications from a lecture in social psychology, but to be honest i haven´t read them by my own.
mood and judgments about ones own life: Schwarz, N., & Clore, G. L. (1983). Mood, misattribution, and judgments of well-being: informative and directive functions of affective states. Journal of personality and social psychology, 45(3), 513.

Comment: happiness and stereotyping: Bodenhausen, G. V., Kramer, G. P., & Süsser, K. (1994). Happiness and stereotypic thinking in social judgment. Journal of personality and social psychology, 66(4), 621.
mood and Persuasion: Bless, H., Bohner, G., Schwarz, N., & Strack, F. (1990). Mood and persuasion: A cognitive response analysis. Personality and social psychology bulletin, 16(2), 331-345.
Maybe These three articles point into the direction you are looking. Or at least give you a start for your search